# How do I configure auto-login in Linux?

Tags: linux, login, slackware

Im using [Vector Linux](http://vectorlinux.com/) and I want to login automatically every system starpup instead ask for user and password.

P.S. Vector Linux is based in slackware and uses shell to ask user and password

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [nodm](http://enricozini.org/sw/nodm/) for some ideas.

It is hard to guess from your question if you use a graphical frontend or a shell.

There should be support in `gdm` (Gnome) and `kdm` (KDE) as well.

I'm not familiar with Vector Linux, but in some Gnome distros there is a `gdm` config file `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`. Put in it something like this:

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=whatever_username
```